# AVPlayer and Control Center

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, control-center

I am developing an application that plays a live web radio streaming and ipod music via AVPlayer. Is it possible to show the current item meta data in control center ? if yes, how is that accomplished ? Thanks.